# Grouping on a multislect field

Tags: reporting, multi-select

Is it possible to do a grouping on a report for multiselect field? 
What i need is if the selections are 'red,green,white' and 'red,white'. the grouping of  2 reds and 2 whites and 1 green records

I understand this is a limitation on SF for a pretty long time. Has anyone got a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried "bucketing" the the selections in the way you've described? The only other way I can think of would possibly be to apply a cross-filter. Unfortunately, I don't have any multi-select objects I can think of that I can use to run a report on to test this out for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A work around i have used in the past is to create a formula field for each of the permutations of the multi select that you want to track. I've used a number formula to make record counts easier in reports but the new boolean formulas in summer 13 could be a good alternative

IF(Includes(Multi_Select_1__c , "White"),1,0)

one of these for each colour should get you the calculation in a SF report that you described.

Answer (score -1):

You can write a custom Visualforce page that identifies all the possible different values, then groups them.

Comment: He's talking about running Reports, not displaying a VF page.

Comment: I understand he's talking about running Reports, but he can't DO that in a report, and he asked for a workaround, which I gave him.